# Avro performance Issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro, azure-hdinsight, gzip

We are having text File(12GB), converted same file to Avro File (3 GB),  and gz(2.5GB) File, when we created external hive table pointing to respective files and ran Select count(*) => Flat File returning results in 5-6 mins, gz => 4-5 mins and Avro took 8 mins.

My Avro Schema has string,double and ints. I have around 201 columns in schema.

I read Avro should improve performance while reading the avro file. but i result shows Gz ( with single mapper) is performing better than Plain text (6 Mappers) and plain text is better than avro ( 3 mappers). Is there a way to improve the performance of avro file.

As per different blogs, Avro is showing better results than gz and text file. is there some thing Im missing in hive settings. Im already using TEZ engine.